# Commutators Calculus

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

[image]

I was trying to understand the above Corollary but I have a problem, namely why in the second to last line $A_0 \leq \zeta_p(G)$? Any ideas?

**Definitions**

By recurrence we define $[x,_0\, y]=x$; $[x, _{i+1}\, y]=[[x, _i\, y],\, y]$

$\zeta_n(G)$ is $n$-th center of $G$.

Comment: Can you please define $\zeta_n(G)$ and ${}_p x$?

Comment: I've now defined them in the question.

Comment: Yeah I tought that, but doesn't the definition require a not fixed $x$? I found that $Z_k(G)$ is contained in the set of elements $a$ such that $[a,_k\, x]=1$ but not the converse. Why the converse still hold?

Comment: By the way, just for my own interest, from which book is this?

Comment: http://web.math.unifi.it/users/casolo/lavoro/otranto2007.pdf

Comment: Thanks, interesting piece of work!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[A_0,_p,x] = [[A_0,_{p-1},x],x]=1$, so $x$ centralizes $[[A_0,_{p-1},x]$, and $N$ does also, so $C_G([A_0,_{p-1},x])$ contains $\langle N,x \rangle = G$. i.e. $[[A_0,_{p-1},x] \in \zeta_1(G)$.

Then we get $x$ centralizes $[[A_0,_{p-2},x]$ modulo $\zeta_1(G)$, so $[[A_0,_{p-2},x] \le \zeta_2(G)$, etc.